# mysql/php Auto update database on certain dates

Tags: php, mysql

Hi am not entirely sure if this is possible but appreciate any information given,

I am creating a site that will have challenges on it and once a challenge is complete I would like for the site to automatically insert information into my news feeds.

Something like:

> **CHALLENGE COMPLETE**
>
> Winner is Robert with 200 points.

For example if the challenge ends on 21st June 2012, 13:01 then once that date and time comes it will automatically insert the information. I would prefer it not relying on user interaction for this to happen.

I have tried searching but I don't know what this is actually called or if it can be done.

Comment: Where is your news feed coming from? Database? Or some text file? Is there some other stuff in that feed besides the challenge result?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CRON timer at daily basis if your server supports that. It'll run a php script at a certain time (for example every day at 2:00am) that checks if there are any challenges completed today (or yesterday) and runs the necessary operations for those. The CRON commands you can use:

If you can directly call the php file (because sometimes it'd be an rewrited url and you can't tell it to the php executable):

**/usr/bin/php /path/to/your/phpfile.php**

And the second possibility as I mentioned above:

**/usr/bin/wget -q -O http://www.yourdomain.com/scripts/phpfile**

**/usr/bin/curl http://www.yourdomain.com/scripts/phpfile**

Comment: it turns out my host wont let me turn the event scheduler on and advised me to use cron..

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use cron as suggested in the comments above, you might want to take a look at [MySQL's event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) - available since MySQL 5.1.6. E.g.:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT '2012-06-21 13:01:00'
    DO
      // your INSERT query here
```